# Firebase Functions Upgrading to Node 8

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Does the version of Node.js on my development machine / integrated development environment (IDE) machine have any effect on my ability to upgrade my Firebase Cloud Functions Node.js runtime to version 8?

I finally got my functions Node.js runtime upgraded to v8 but I had a difficult time doing it. I eventually installed node version manager, nvm, to nail my development machines Node version to 8.0.0 but then ran into the 8.0.0 issue w/ `firebase-tools`. ["must use 8.1.0. 8.0.0 fails"](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/356#issuecomment-307162235)

```
nvm install v8.1.0
nvm alias default 8.1.0
```

So, running Node.js v8.1.0 on my development machine seemed to be the breakthrough. I'd like to know but don'e have time to spend on recreating it all.